# Entity Framework : Group by and Join

Tags: c#, join, group-by, entity-framework-6

I need to get some statistics from the database, but I can't get it to work as I want. I have two tables, Task and Status, and I need to get the number of Tasks per Status, for example, if I have the statuses New and Closed, and each Task has exactly one Status, I want a list like this:

```
New      35
Closed   47
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var statistics = database.Task
            .GroupBy(t => t.StatusId)
            .Select(g => new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```

This returns the StatusId and the Task count, so all I need to do is to replace the StatusId with Status.Name. Basically I need to combine the above with a join the table Status and then get the Status.Name. But here I fail, can anyone help me?

Comment: If you model your entities correctly to have navigational properties, you wouldn't have to join. Can you show your entity classes?

Comment: do you not have a FK on the Status table?? EF should generate the proxy child class as part of task if you have done this - you would then find `t.Status.Name` inside the linq query

Comment: I have foreign keys, and normally I would do t.Status.Name but inside the Select() I don't have access to t I guess. It does not work anyway.

Comment: if your table have `StatusName`  in it  then what effort you made for your question,that was all to replace `StatusId` with `StatusName`  @Hultan

Comment: @Viplock I don't have StatusName in my table, I had to make some adjustments, see below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var statistics = database.Task
    .GroupBy(t => new { Id = t.StatusId, Name = t.Status.Name })
    .Select(g => new { StatusId = g.Key.Id, StatusName = g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i don't think task table have `statusname` in it .So it wont work

Comment: I just needed to make some small adjustments:

Comment: var statistics = database.Task
            .GroupBy(t => new { Id = t.StatusId, Name = t.Status.Name })
            .Select(g => new { Series = 1, Status = g.Key.Name, Count = g.Count() })
            .ToList();

Comment: @Hultan: I edited my answer accordingly. You should also accept an aswer if it was excatly what you needed...

Comment: @JanPalas: Just clicking the checkbox, right? Correct now?

Comment: @Hultan: Yes, exactly ;-)